# Parsing JSON list with JsonObject library in Dart

Tags: json, dart

I'm trying to parse some JSON with the help of the JsonOject library. I'm getting the following exception:

```
 Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map' of 'value'.
```

My code:

```js
class MyList extends JsonObject implements List { 
  MyList();

  factory MyList.fromString(String jsonString) {
    return new JsonObject.fromJsonString(jsonString, new MyList());
  }
}

class MyResult extends JsonObject { 
  num Dis;
  int Flag;
  MyProduct Obj;
}

class MyProduct extends JsonObject { 
  int ID;
  String Title;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```js
var testJson = """
  [{"Dis":1111.1,"Flag":0,"Obj":{"ID":1,"Title":"Volvo 140"}},
  {"Dis":2222.2,"Flag":0,"Obj":{"ID":2,"Title":"Volvo 240"}}]
""";
MyList list = new MyList.fromString(testJson);
//I want to be able to do something like this.
//print(list[0].Obj.Title);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've updated my [JsonObject github repo](https://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject) to fix this bug.  I've also added a [passing unit test](https://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject/blob/master/test/test_list.dart) that reproduces this.

You'll need to run `pub update` to get the latest version of the library.

The following code now works:

```
import 'package:json_object/json_object.dart';

void main() {
  var testJson = """
      [{"Dis":1111.1,"Flag":0,"Obj":{"ID":1,"Title":"Volvo 140"}},
      {"Dis":2222.2,"Flag":0,"Obj":{"ID":2,"Title":"Volvo 240"}}]""";
  MyList list = new MyList.fromString(testJson);
  //I want to be able to do something like this.
  print(list[0].Obj.Title);  // <- now prints "Volvo 140"
}

class MyList extends JsonObject implements List { 
  MyList();

  factory MyList.fromString(String jsonString) {
    return new JsonObject.fromJsonString(jsonString, new MyList());
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the children parsed also so that the both the following are true? `print(list[0] is MyResult);
print(list[0].Obj is MyProduct);`

Comment: I suspect not.  Everything down the tree is a JsonObject apart from the top-level class.  On my todo list is a reflection based JsonObject, which I hope would cover these scenarios (but don't wait for it :)  One way you might achieve that might be to use the raw JSON parser to convert the incoming JSON to a List of Maps, and then use JsonObject.fromMap() constructor to convert each Map into a JsonObject.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just wanted to check if there was an easy way that I had missed.