# Secure and easy transfer of MySql data from server to client

Tags: json, webserver, dart, dart-io

I have a piece of Dart in my server-side app and I have no idea how to transform the map delivered by MySql into a JSON-type structure, to send these data to the client.
Secure: no way of Sql-injection;
easy: only a few line of code to convert data, taking in account that a string contains string-delimiters (' or "), that don't allow for a simple concat.
On the client I decode a JSON string and populate the form.
this is the server routine:

```dart
 void handlePost(HttpRequest req) {
   HttpResponse res = req.response; 
    req.listen((List<int> buffer) {
     addCorsHeaders(res);  
     AsciiDecoder a = new AsciiDecoder();
     String s = a.convert(buffer); // contains key data in JSON-string
     Map data = JSON.decode(s);
     if (data.containsKey("key")){
       var r1 = data{"key"};      
       pool.query('select fi, la, age from person where keyT =' + r1).then((result) {
         result.forEach((row) {
             print("FirstName: ${row[0]}, lastName: ${row[1]}, Age: ${row[2]}");
             closeRes(res, JSONdata);
         });
       });
     }
     else closeRes(res, "NOK missing key");
   },
   onError: printError);
 }
```

Where I wrote `print("FirstName: ${row[0]}, lastName: ${row[1]}, Age: ${row[2]}");`
I'd write some code that transforms the MySql map into something, that I can transform in the client to a JSON-something. 
On the Client I have this:

```dart
 void getDataFromServer(){
   HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); // create a new XHR  
   request.onReadyStateChange.listen((_) {
     if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
        (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0)) {
       extractJson(request.responseText); // output the response 
     }
   });  
   request.open("POST", url, async: false);
   request.send(jsonData); // POST string like: {"key":"12345"}
 }
```

Can someone some lines of code, showing how-to? or show me an article that has some working example? I'm running newest version of Dart.
I used (for 15 years) to write desktop app's in VBasic, trying now to convert.

Comment: I think all what you need is here on StackOverflow. Just use the search function. 'Give me some code' questions are off topic on SO.

Comment: If so, reread my question as: What DART routine can transform a MySql map returned by SqlJocky into a Jason-map.

Comment: For secure transfer, use SSL encryption.

Comment: Secure in the sense, that I don't upload html-injection type of data. I can't find any routines (like in php) that transform all special chars in &things;

Comment: Dart automatically sanitizes any html content inserted into a page without a validator. Maybe it does the same for user input. I need to check.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for the encoding to JSON in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024298/add-json-serializer-to-every-model-class). Set all fields in the class that describes the sql-table to the results obtained by mySql and serialize. Concat all rows. Then pass the string to the client.

Awaiting the answer from  Nawaf Alsulami for the injection part of the question