# dart: get all variable names within a class

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to get all declared variables within a class in dart? So what I want to do is get all variables in a list from a class and check each variable if it's null. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show what you’ve tried for now ?

Comment: I wasn't clear the first time. I just edited it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819222/getting-all-of-the-variables-of-a-dart-class-for-json-encoding