# How to make a JSON object and pass this JSON object into an external JavaScript function?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm developing a game in Dart, and I want to migrate the drawing to PIXI.js. Basically one approach that occurred to me is to convert the game state into a JSON object, and pass this JSON object to an external JS method, which would then create the PIXI containers.

How do I make a JSON object and how do I pass it to an external JavaScript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';

...

var json = JSON.encode(data);
...
var data = JSON.decode(json);
```

You probably want to use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js for dart-js-interop.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.encode` and `JSON.decode` are that, what you are looking for, but they are work good with primitive types (be careful, for example DateTime - is not primitive) and collections of primitive types. So if you want to do it for object, you should convert it to map/from map. Conversion to map can be called automatically when object is passed to `JSON.encode`, if this object has method `Map toJson()`, conversion from map should be done explicitly (for example, with constructor with `Map` parameter).

Also, that can be useful: I prefer to avoid implicit `toJson` call, cause when it throws exception, you will not see its message and call stack in this case.

Useful links and some info about this can be found [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20024298/5521491).